# Why does laradock use workspace container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I'm using laradock to build environment for my project that is using laravel. Every is good but I don't understand why laradock uses workspace container separately with php-fpm. In other hand, I can build a docker-compose file with nginx, php-fpm, mysql and can run project properly.

My question is why does laradock use workspace container?

Answer (score 1):

The workspace container is used to run cron jobs, run linux commands and scripts in an environment that has access to php, mysql, mongo or other needed services. For example you can use it to run phpunit tests or run migration scripts.

You can enter the workspace container with : 
`docker-compose exec workspace bash`